# Clear a ReadOnly List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, csla

I Need to Clear my CSLA ReadOnly List which is of course not possible because CSLA is protecting my ReadOnly Lst. I also cant simply set the List null because that is removing the FilterMethods of my List in the XAML. is there a way to make an own Clear Method in my `ReadOnlyListBase` ?

Short:

- ShowGroupPanel in the UI of WPF is false when I set the List on null.
- I cant clear/remove the List because it has to be ReadOnly.

So is there maybe a way to return a Empty List in the ReadOnlyListBase Object?

Comment: Can you set your variable to refer to a *new* `ReadOnlyList`?

Comment: u r right, I only thought in the "csla" way

Comment: Baby seals get slapped in the face everytime someone adds a Clear method in ReadOnly collections. Plz think of the seals!

Comment: Instead you should internally hold an `List<T>` while you give out an `IReadOnlyList<T>`. By that approach the owner of the list can add, remove, clear the list while each consumer  can only read it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with a new `ObservableRangeCollection` like this:

```
SelectedDates = new ObservableRangeCollection<DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with atomaras, clearing a readonly collection is a bad idea.

But if you *really* want to do this, you can implement a public method on your collection class that sets the protected IsReadOnly property to false, clears the collection, then sets IsReadOnly to true again.

Not a good idea, but certainly something that will work.

Comment: I made a public method called ClearList which is just returning a List.New();